# How to monitor site tracking code health as well as sitecatalyst health?

Tags: adobe-analytics

Lets say, I have a website which uses site catalyst for analyticial purpose. Now I would like to monitor the site health on hourly basis whether,

- Site Catalyst tracking is working properly or not(only few metrics - page view,  revenue)
- Site Catalyst(Adobe) is down or not. (Not most likely, but still would like to track it)

Currently we are manually generating reports on hourly basis to monitor the health. I would like to reduce the manual efforts and want to know whether

1. Is it possible to automate the process? (using report builder or APIs).
2. If so, any guidelines or useful links for implementing the same would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup [alerts](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/user/alerts.html) for your reports, and you can see general status of Adobe Marketing Cloud stuff [here](http://status.adobe.com/marketing_cloud) (Adobe Analytics > Marketing Reports and Analytics is what SiteCatalyst is now called)

Comment: Alerts is a nice option. But will it work, in case, if Adobe Analytics is down? As far as status is concerned, I need to go to the page every hour and check whether everything is fine or not. What I'm looking at is to automate the monitor process.